# Writing CSV File with ShouldQuote doesn't write the quotes

Tags: csvhelper

I am trying to surround specific fields with double quotes when writing CSV files when using CsvWriter. I set the ShouldQuote property of the configuration to a function, and passed the configuration to the CsvWriter. It doesn't write the quotes around the fields.

```
protected virtual bool ReportShouldQuote(ShouldQuoteArgs args)
        {
            return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Field) && args.FieldType == typeof(string));
        }
```

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                ShouldQuote = ReportShouldQuote
            };

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath))
            using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config))
            {
                csv.WriteHeader<T>();
                csv.NextRecord();

                TotalRows = 0;

                while (dataReader.Read()) // Read data row by row
                {
                    var mappedData = mapFunc(dataReader); // Map data using the provided function
                    csv.WriteRecord(mappedData); // Write the mapped data to CSV
                    csv.NextRecord(); // Move to the next record
                    TotalRows++;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to write the quotes around any string that is not null or empty for me.

```
"Id","Name"
1,"Name_1"
2,"Name_2"
3,
4,"Name_4"
5,"Name_5"
```

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        ShouldQuote = ReportShouldQuote
    };

    using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, config))
    {
        csv.WriteHeader<Foo>();
        csv.NextRecord();

        var TotalRows = 0;

        while (TotalRows < 5) // Read data row by row
        {
            TotalRows++;
            
            var mappedData = new Foo {Id = TotalRows, Name = "Name_" + TotalRows};
            
            if (TotalRows == 3)
                mappedData.Name = string.Empty;
                
            csv.WriteRecord(mappedData);
            csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }
}

protected virtual bool ReportShouldQuote(ShouldQuoteArgs args)
{
    return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Field) && args.FieldType == typeof(string));
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```